# Edit cell properties in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am a beginner in JQ grid. In my JQ grid I have a image in a column added as an anchor tag. Onclick of the particular cell I need to change the image only for that cell. I am adding a class 'clickableTitle' to the column and trying to access the current cell as:

```
$('.clickableTitle').live('click', function () {
    $(this).parents('table:first').getCell($(this).parents('tr:first').attr('id'), 'comment'));
 });
```

This gives me the anchor tag in below format, but I am not able to change its image source at runtime.

```
<A href="Proj.aspx?PID=795&Store=#Comment"><IMG class=commentIcon src="/_Layouts/images/iconCommentOn.png"></A>
```

Can you please let me know what would be the best way to achieve this. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all the name of the JavaScript library which you try to use: **jqGrid**. Everywhere in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs) or on [the main side](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) you will find the same name written in exact the same form.

To your main question. It seems you can just use `onCellSelect` callback to catch the click event on the image or just a click on some cell. The `e` parameter of the `onCellSelect` callback is the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and the `e.target` will the the element which was clicked.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ChangeImageOnClick.htm) demonstrate how you can use it.

[image]

I used as the initial background image of jQuery UI for the lock.

```js
formatter: function () {
    return "<a href='#'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-locked'></span></a>"
}
```

Clicking on the image changed the image by changing the class on the `<span>` element from `"ui-icon-locked"` to `"ui-icon-unlocked"`:

```js
onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
    var $dest = $(e.target), $td = $dest.closest('td');
    if ($td.hasClass("clickableTitle")) {
        if ($dest.hasClass("ui-icon-locked")) {
            $dest.removeClass("ui-icon-locked").addClass("ui-icon-unlocked");
        } else {
            $dest.removeClass("ui-icon-unlocked").addClass("ui-icon-locked");
        }
    }
}
```

You can easy change the code if you prefer to have `<img>` instead of background image in `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

@Oleg: Thanks for your input. I am sure that urs is the right way to go about it, but I had to use the solution mentioned below because of the limitations of existing implementation.

```
$('.clickableTitle').live('click', function () { 
    $('body').css('cursor', 'wait'); 
    var commentIconStat = $(this).parents('table:first').getCell($(this).parents('tr:first').attr('id'), 'comment');  
    //Turn read comment off 
    if (commentIconStat.search(/iconCommentOn/i) > -1) { 
        commentIconStat = commentIconStat.replace(/iconCommentOn/i, "iconCommentOff"); 
        $(this).parents('table:first').setCell($(this).parents('tr:first').attr('id'), 'comment', commentIconStat, '')

    } 
    $('body').css('cursor', 'default'); 
});
```