# Display tooltip in JQ Grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, tooltip

I am using jqgrid to display data i need "Click Here to Edit " in all cells and "Click here to delete" for delete button cell

which is the best way to show this kind of tool tip in jqgrid?

Is it possible to add with

```
colNames: ['ROLEID', "Name", "", ""], 
colModel: [
    { name: 'ROLEID', index: 'ROLEID', width: 10, hidden: true, key: true }, 
    { name: 'ROLENAME', index: 'ROLENAME', width: 50, editable: true,
        search: false}, 
    { name: '', index: '', search: false, width: 30, align: "center",
        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            var btnDelete =
                '<div class="round-icon-btn close right delete_step" id=btnId_' +
                 options.rowId + ' ></div>';
            return btnDelete;
        }},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cellattr` property to set custom tooltip on in the column:

```
{ name: 'mydelete', search: false, width: 30, align: "center",
    cellattr: function () { return ' title="Click here to delete"'; },
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        var btnDelete =
            '<div class="round-icon-btn close right delete_step" id=btnId_' +
             options.rowId + ' ></div>';
        return btnDelete;
    }}
```

Moreover I don't think that setting of `id` attribute on the custom button is really required. To handle click on the custom button you can use `onCellSelect` or `beforeSelectRow` callbacks. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9946955/315935), [this old one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305904/315935).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this discussion

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/tooltip-on-row-hover-with-ajax-content-solution/

Comment: And dont forget to add the div id -> <div id="tooltip"></div> and add style tag <style>#tooltip{position:absolute;}</style>