# jQuery - jqGrid - undesired behavior in onSelectRow event

Tags: jquery, events, jqgrid

I had a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717459/jquery-jqgrid-submit-buttons-in-each-row) regarding having buttons available in each row of a jqGrid, that would activate when the row was selected.  With help from `@Oleg` I was able to get it to work like I thought it should.

In further testing however, I have identified undesired behavior in that `onSelectRow` event.  What I found was that if I have a grid with 3 rows in it, and I click on row 2 (which activates the buttons), then (without clicking on the row 2 buttons) click on row 3 (which deactivates row 2 buttons & activates row 3 buttons), and change my mind again & click row 1 or 2 (doesn't matter), and at **THAT** point then click the `"Re-Send"` (submit) button, what happens is that the selected row is then re-sent 3 separate times.

Following are the timestamps from 4 rows that were written from 1 "Re-Send" click yesterday.

```
2013-05-28 16:49:04.817
2013-05-28 16:49:04.653
2013-05-28 16:49:04.560
2013-05-28 16:49:04.467
```

I put some logging in the page & confirmed that it does call the POST 4 separate times, once for each click on a row in the grid.

The following sections contain most of the configuration/settings I currently have where the jqGrid gets built.

```
colNames: ["Destination", "Message Text", "Send Time","Message Action"],
colModel:[
    {name:"Destination",index:"Destination",width:col1width,align:"left", xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>Destination",sortable:false},
    {name:"MessageText",index:"MessageText",width:col2width,align:"left",xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>MessageText",sortable:false},
    {name:"SendTime",index:"SendTime",width:col3width,align:"center",formatter:"date",formatoptions: {"srcformat":"ISO8601Long", "newformat":"Y-m-d H:i:s"},xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>SendTime",sortable:false},
    {name: "msgAct",
    width: col4width,
    align: "center",
    formatter: function() {
        return "<input name='resendMsg' style='height:25px;width:65px;' type='submit' value='Re-Send' disabled='disabled' />" +
               "<input name='cancelMsg' style='height:25px;width:55px;' type='submit' value='Cancel' disabled='disabled' />" 
            }}
    ],
viewrecords: true,
caption: capMsg,
rownum: 0,
height: "100%",
width: gridwidth,
toolbar: [true, "top"],
pager: jQuery("#pager1"),
sortname: "SendTime",
hidegrid: false,                // hides the ability to collapse grid
defaults: {
    altrows: true, 
    recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {2}",
    emptyrecords:  "No records to view",
    loadonce: true,
    pgtext: "Page  {0} of {1}"
    },
```

Following is the `onSelectRow` event.

```
onSelectRow:  function(id) {
    var tr = $(this).jqGrid("getInd",id,true);
    var gridRow = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData",id);
    var srow = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam","selrow");
    // disable all resendMsg & cancelMsg buttons in the grid
    $(this).find("input[name=resendMsg]").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $(this).find("input[name=cancelMsg]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    // now enable the buttons for the current row only
    $(tr).find("input[name=resendMsg]").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(tr).find("input[name=cancelMsg]").removeAttr("disabled");
    // disable dropdowns & sendMsg submit button
    // catch the Cancel button click
    $(tr).find("input[name=cancelMsg]").click(function() {
        // disable all resendMsg & cancelMsg buttons in the grid
        $(this).find("input[name=resendMsg]").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $(this).find("input[name=cancelMsg]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        // enable the dropdowns & clear the selection, reload grid
        ReloadGrid();
        });
    // catch the Re-Send button click
    $(tr).find("input[name=resendMsg]").click(function() {
        ReSendMessage(gridRow.Destination, gridRow.MessageText);
        // disable all resendMsg & cancelMsg buttons in the grid
        $(this).find("input[name=resendMsg]").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $(this).find("input[name=cancelMsg]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        // enable the dropdowns, clear the selection and exit
        $("#myGrid").jqGrid("resetSelection");
        });
    },
```

and the remainder of the jqGrid code:

```
gridview: true,
xmlReader:  { 
    root: "Rowsets", 
            row: "Row",
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "SendTime"
    },
loadComplete: function() { 
    // increase row height
    $("td",".jqgrow").height(40);            // data grid rows
     // alternate background of every other row
    $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css({"background-color": "#DDDDDC", "background-image": "none"});
    $("th.ui-th-column").css("font-weight","bold");
    }
});
```

It's like the onSelectRow event is accumulating the number of clicks & then calling the click event's functions however many times a row was selected but a button wasn't clicked.

I have tested though, that if I click on a row, and then click on either of the submit buttons, that it processes as expected (a "`Re-Send`" submits the row 1 time, and a "`Cancel`" clears the selection & does nothing else).

I don't know if it is possible, but can you prevent a subsequent `onSelectRow` from firing if a row's already selected?  Can you clear the previous selection (or reset it) to prevent the `onSelectRow` (and the click event for the button) from firing multiple times?

I'd appreciate any thoughts, comments or suggestions as to how to fix this behavior.

**EDIT**

Including the code for `beforeSelectRow` as noted in a response below.

```
$("#myGrid").bind("jqGridBeforeSelectRow", function(e, id, eventOriginal) {
    var gsr = $("#myGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam","selrow");
    console.log(" ****  beforeSelectRow - (before if) lastSel = " + lastSel + "  id = " + id + "   gsr = " + gsr);
    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
        console.log("id && id !== lastSel");
        console.log("   id = " + id +  "    lastSel = " + lastSel);
        };
    if (id !== lastSel) {
        if (lastSel == -1) {   // first time thru
            lastSel = id;
            console.log(" ****  beforeSelectRow - first time thru - new val = " + lastSel + "  gsr = " + gsr);
            return true;
            }
          else {
            console.log(" ****  beforeSelectRow - lastSel - " + lastSel + "   <>  id = "  +id + "    gsr = " + gsr);
            return false;
            }
        }
    else {
        console.log(" ****  beforeSelectRow - otherwise they matched -  lastSel  = " + lastSel + "     id = " + id + "  gsr = " + gsr);
        return true;
        }
    });
```

After moving the `.click` event from the `onSelectRow` into the `loadComplete` (for the Cancel button as a test), I tried the above code both inside & outside the code for the grid.  It performs the same either way.

The issue is that the `Cancel` button is supposed to reset the selection `$("#myGrid").resetSelection();` and reload the grid.  The code executes & doesn't give an error, but the very next time `beforeSelectRow` fires (when the grid is reloaded), the id is still the same as it was when `beforeSelectRow` and `onSelectRow` fired when I clicked on the row, which means that I can never select a new row until the entire page is reloaded.  Only on page load is when `beforeSelectRow` doesn't fire.

**EDIT**

Following is the code for the Cancel button, which is now located inside the `loadComplete` event.

```
// catch the Cancel button click
$(this).find("input[name=cancelMsg]").click(function() {
    // disable all resendMsg & cancelMsg buttons in the grid
    $(this).find("input[name=resendMsg]").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $(this).find("input[name=cancelMsg]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    // enable the dropdowns & clear the selection, reload grid
    console.log("ReloadGrid (inside Cancel function) ");
    lastSel = -1;
    $("#myGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wrong to bind button (to use `.click`) inside of `onSelectRow` callback.

Instead of you can move the code with registering `click` event handler inside of `loadComplete`. You can just move the code from `onSelectRow` to `loadComplete` and replace `$(tr)` to `$(this)` to search inside of *all* buttons of the grid and not only the buttons of selected row. You can still set or remove `disabled` attribute inside of `onSelectRow` callback.

More better would be to make *no individual binding* for every button. One can just use `onCellSelect` or `beforeSelectRow` which will be called from `click` handler bound on *whole* grid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9946955/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) for code examples.

**UPDATED**: I am not sure that I understand correctly your problem, but I hope that [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomButton2.htm) will demonstrate the solution of the problem. I don't used any explicit `click` handler. The most important change (which could important if you use Internet Explorer) is adding `class='cbox'` to the formatter to prevent `return` in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L2650) of jqGrid code. The most important part of the code is below

```
colModel: [
    { name: "text", width: 500 },
    { name: "msgAct", width: 150,
        formatter: function () {
            return "<input name='resendMsg' class='cbox' style='height:25px;width:65px;' type='submit' value='Re-Send' disabled='disabled'/>" +
                "<input name='cancelMsg'  class='cbox' style='height:25px;width:55px;' type='submit' value='Cancel' disabled='disabled'/>"
        }}
],
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var tr = $(this).jqGrid("getInd", rowid, true);
    $(this).find("input[name=resendMsg],input[name=cancelMsg]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(tr).find("input[name=resendMsg],input[name=cancelMsg]").removeAttr("disabled");
},
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $self = $(this),
        $td = $(e.target).closest("td"),
        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]),
        name = $(e.target).attr("name");
    if (this.p.colModel[iCol].name === "msgAct") {
        if (name === "resendMsg") {
            alert("'Re-Send' button clicked in the row with id=" + rowid +
                "\ntext in the row =\"" + $self.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "text") + "\"");
        } else if (name === "cancelMsg") {
            alert("'Cancel' button clicked in the row with id=" + rowid);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
            }, 50);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can replace alerts inside of `beforeSelectRow` to the action which you need.

Comment: Moving the `.click` into the `loadComplete` helped to have it get called only once.  However, I've noticed that the `rowID` is still the value it was, and isn't resetting, even though I am calling `$("#myGrid").ResetSelection();` from inside the `.click` event handler that's moved into the `loadComplete`.  That means that if I have 3 rows displayed & select row 3, then hit the cancel button on the row, the `beforeSelectRow` still has row 3's id in it & unless I reload the page, I can never select any other row until the page is reloaded.  I have included the `beforeSelectRow` code above.

Comment: @steve_o: You wrote about problems with "reload the grid" inside of `beforeSelectRow`, but the code which you posed don't contain any trigger reloadGrid. Could you include the code which shows *how* you do this? Do you call trigger reloadGrid inside of `setTimeout`? Do you reset variables like `lastSel` before reloading? I don't understand some parts of the code which you posted. Why you access `selrow` inside of `jqGridBeforeSelectRow` instead of usage `id` parameter?

Comment: Added the code above.  To answer your questions:  I do not call trigger reloadGrid inside of `setTimeout`.  Variable `lastSel` is set to -1 within the Cancel click event.  The `selrow` inside the `jqGridBeforeSelectRow` is for information as used in the `console.log` statements.  I was displaying `id` in the `beforeSelectRow` and could see that it wasn't being reset - `selrow` was being displayed to show me that the selected row had indeed been reset.  I'm not sure how the `id` ever gets reset.

Comment: @steve_o: Look at **UPDATED** part of my answer and [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomButton2.htm).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I've got it working to some degree.  However, what I notice is that `onSelectRow` fires every time the grid loads after the first time.  I took your suggestion & moved the button actions into the `beforeSelectRow`.  Some of the code I omitted was disabling dropdown boxes in the `onSelectRow`.  Since (after the first time) `onSelectRow` fires every time they're never being re-enabled (as the grid is).  Since `onSelectRow` fires, I think that I need to detect `selected` also.  Thoughts?  Thank you again for **ALL** of your help!

Comment: I may have resolved the issue.  Unless there is a better way to do it, I put the code to turn on everything turned off in the `onSelectRow` inside the resend/cancel `if` statements in `beforeSelectRow`.  In there, I'd re-enable anything previously disabled, and disable anything that was currently enabled, reset the selection and then reload the grid.  After that (still inside the `if resend` or `if cancel`) I would return `false` from `beforeSelectRow`.  Not finished testing it, but it seems to do what I am asking.  **Thank you again for all your help!!**

Comment: @steve_o: You are welcome! Sorry, but you can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomButton2_.htm) that no `onSelectRow` will be fired by loading the grid. If you have the effect that you should examine your code where you explicitly select some row.

Comment: - your demo code is actually what helped me figure out how to fix it.  I put a log message into both `onSelectRow` and `beforeSelectRow` to see what was happening.  On page load, no `onSelectRow` fired.  However, once I selected a row, no matter whether I hit `Re-Send` or `Cancel` - `onSelectRow` would always fire.  What I ended up doing was when `Re-Send` or `Cancel` button was handled in the `beforeSelectRow` was where I did the reloading of the grid & had it return **FALSE**.  Otherwise, `beforeSelectRow` would return **TRUE**.  Thank you again!