# OnClick on custom button created on JqGrid row get json parameter

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

Hi I have the following jqgrid columns, onclick on approve button I need to send an ID to servlet thro ajax.

```
colNames: ['EmployeeID','Name', 'From Date', 'To Date', 'Reason', ''],
    colModel: [
           {name:'employeeID', index:'emp_Id', width:55 },
           {name: 'employeeName', index:'name', width:90},
           {name: 'leave_from', index:'from_date', width: 90},
           {name: 'leave_to', index:'to_date', width: 90},
           {name: 'reason', index:'status', width: 90},
           {name: 'option', index: 'option', width:150, sortable:false},
               ],
```

**Custom Button Code**

```
    loadComplete: function(){
        //alert('loading Complete');
        var id = jQuery('#jqqGrid').getDataIDs();
        for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++){
            //var c1 = id[i];
            approve = "<input style='height:22px;width:60px;' type='button' onclick= \"approveLeave();\" Value='Approve'/><br />";
            reject = "<input style='height:22px;width:60px;' type='button' onclick= \"rejectLeave();\" Value='Reject'/><br />";
            jQuery('#jqqGrid').jqGrid('setRowData',id[i], {option:approve+reject});
        }
```

I am able to see the buttons in my grid, my problem is to send an ID through onclick function,

**Sample Json object**

```
{"currentPage":1,"totalPages":1,"totalRecords":1,"rows":[{"Id":1016,"cell":{"leave_from":"19/08/2013","leave_to":"23/08/2013","dateofLeaveRequest":"8/18/2013","reason":"Vaccation ","leave_id":1016,"id":0,"employeeID":1029,"employeeName":"Arun Kumar"}}]}
```

I want to pass the ID through my onclick function. Not sure how to achieve it. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's important to understand that jqGrid **always** assign `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements which represents rows of the grid. If you use `"Id":1016` instead of `"id":1016` you should inform jqGrid to use another name for ids. You can include `jsonReader: {id: "Id"}` to do this. Only because jqGrid don't find required information in the input data it assigns integers like 1, 2, 3... as the id values.

The next problem is the usage of `setRowData` in the loop inside of `loadComplete`. I recommend you to read [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) where I tried to explain why the approach is not effective from performance point of view. It would be much better to use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) to construct the content of `option` column. In the case you need define the callback function which jqGrid calls when it need to build the content of `<td>` (the cell of the column `option`). The callback have four parameters `cellvalue`, `options`, `rowObject`, `action`. The second parameter `options` is object which `rowId` property (`options.rowId`) provide you the id of the row. The third parameter `rowObject` represent the input data for the row. I think that it will be something like `{leave_from: "19/08/2013", leave_to: "23/08/2013", dateofLeaveRequest: "8/18/2013", reason: "Vaccation", leave_id: 1016, id: 0, employeeID: 1029, employeeName: "Arun Kumar"}` in your case. In the way you will be able to construct the cell content based on any values of input data of the row. So `rowObject.leave_id` or `options.rowId` will get you the information which you need.

The usage of `'onclick=\"approveLeave(' + options.rowId + ')'` could have some disadvantages in case when you implement some editing of data. In the case `onclick` could use *old* id value. More better will be use `approveLeave(this)`. The value of `this` is the DOM of `<input>` element which was clicked. So you can use `$(elem).closest("tr").attr("id")` (`elem` could be the first parameter of `approveLeave`) to get the rowid.

More better way will be **don't assign any `onclick` at all**. One can set **one** `click` event handle on the whole `<table>` which represent grid. jqGrid do this. So one can just use `beforeSelectRow` or `onSelectRow` to handle `click` on any button inside of the grid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890495/315935).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, I have modified my code removing **setRowData** with **custom formatter** as suggested. I need to have separate buttons with onclick event to either approve or reject leave. This table cells will not be edited. That's the reason I am using onclick event to fire ajax request.

Comment: @AKV: you don't need to set `onclick` handle on *every* button. You can use `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect`. The `e` parameter of the callbacks provide you information *which one* from buttons in the grid was clicked by the user. You can get `value` of the button ('Approve' or 'Reject'), get rowid (`leave_id`) and so on. See references from the last part of my answer. If needed you can make `ajax` call or other actions.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am currently looking at your references.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions, edited my code. I have one more question. After the button click, How do I update my table? will setting trigger re-loadgrid in my approveleave help me?

Comment: @AKV: You are welcome! I don't understand what part of content of the grid should be changed after the button was clicked. You can use `setCell` or `setRowData` to update some part of the grid. To reload the whole grid body you can use `$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");`